# C++ How to approach getters and setters of containers in base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, containers

I'm wondering what's the best method to approach the following design or avoid it.

I have an Object class that I use to handle textures and necessities for drawing them.

```
class Object {
    virtual void draw();
    virtual void setI(int newI) { i == newI; }
    int i;
    std::vector<int> container;
    //etc
};
```

I use this Object class as a base for several other classes.

```
class Button : public Object {
    void draw() override { background.draw(); Object::draw(); } 
    void setI(int newI) override { background.setI(newI); Object::setI(newI); }
    Object background;
}
```

I run into a problem when I add containers to this type of base class, because I want to perform operations on the containers such as push_back, erase, clear, etc., but I don't want to implement a virtual function for each of those. The Button class needs to know when I change a container in its base. The Button class does not override every function of its base, so I do not want to lose the inheritance and have the Button simply contain two Objects.

How would you recommend using containers in such a base class or how would you recommend avoiding this usage?

Comment: What do you mean by "but I don't want to implement a virtual function for each of those". Can you  your design problem.

Comment: @Emadpres The Button needs to know when the container is updated. That would require something like   `virtual void updated();   void insert(...) { container.insert(...); updated(); } void clear() { container.clear(); updated(); }` and so on for every function I need to use of the container

Comment: You don't need to have several virtual function. First create an interface to access/modify containers once in base class ( exactly like your insert(..) and clear(..)). Then you just need a `virtual updated()` and override it in each derived class.

Comment: @Emadpres Either way it's a nasty mess of having to add at least 5 extra functions for every container. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Generally your classes should be defined by what thay do, not what data they hold. That is, they should provide useful domain-level abstractions. If your domain is graphics, then interfaces that operate in terms of containers are way too low level. If your domain is containers then Button has no place in it.

Comment: @n.m. I use SDL, which boils texture drawing down to `SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, srcRect, dstRect);` So the Object class is data driven because its all about altering the srcRect, dstRect, angle, alpha, color, etc. Maybe I've thrown too much into this class, because it also has a separately sizable bounding box (to check if mouse clicked) that follows the dstRect around. Button uses this to manage when an Object is clicked and released. Any further recommendation?

Comment: I'd say Button should not inherit Object, but contain one, and subscribe for changes in it (via the Observer pattern).